# openMP lastprivate and firstprivate to the same variable

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

Is it correct apply firstprivate and lastprivate at the same variable?

For example:

```
void main (){
    int a= 100, i;
    #pragma omp for firstprivate(a) lastprivate(a)
    for(i = 0; i <9; i++){
        bla bla bla;
    }
    printf("a= %d",a);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written in the [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) version 4.0, Section 2.14.3:

> A list item that specifies a given variable may not appear in more than one clause on the same directive, except that a variable may be specified in both `firstprivate` and `lastprivate` clauses.

It actually makes a lot of sense to allow for that. `firstprivate` affects the value of the list variables on entry into the parallel region, while `lastprivate` affects them on exit from the region. Both are non-conflicting and their combined use allows for certain variables to "propagate" through the region and get their values modified by the parallel code in the same way as in the sequential case. It mostly makes sense with parallel loops.

Comment: What's not clear to me is when you can use `lastprivate`. According to this [link](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LastprivateClause) it only works for iterators so in the OPs example I think it would only work for `i` and not `a`. That would be useless in th OPs example but if it was something like `for(i = 0; i <(N/8)*8; i++)` it could used to determine that the last iteration was a multiple of 8 and N was not a multiple of 8 in case you need a cleanup loop `for(; i<N; i++)` afterwards.

Comment: @Zboson, `lastprivate` works in combination with worksharing constructs to expose the value of the listed variable(s) assigned during the last logical loop iteration / lexically last section, no matter which thread executes it. If `bla bla bla` in the OPs example would be something like `a = 2*i;` then the value of `a` after the parallel region will be `16`. The page you've linked to shows that it is not possible to use `lastprivate` to extract values assigned during iterations before the last one; it doesn't say that the clause works for iterators only.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. If in that link it had used firstprivate as well rather than getting totally bogus values it would have got the initial values (done=4 and done=5) but that's really not what was wanted either. I see that private value has to be defined by the thread doing the last iteration otherwise the returned value is either undefined or the value of firstprivate.

Answer (score 0):

In firstprivate(x) and in the clause of parallel region the variable x can be recognized as initial variable with some value which was defined somewhere to all the team threads.Each team thread owns its own private x.
In lastprivate(x) in the clause of parallel region, it is about the last iteration of loops. x will be given the final value in the last iteration.